# Namespaced resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

This is an excerpt from my config/routes.rb file:

```
resources :accounts do |account|

      account.resource :profile, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]

      account.resources :posts,
                        :collection => { :fragment => :get },
                        :has_many => [:comments, :likes]

      # even more code

end
```

I would like that each nested resource to be loaded from from the account namespace such as **Account::PostsController** instead of **PostsController**.

Using resources `:accounts, :namespace => 'account'` tries to load AccountPostsController.

Trying to nest the structure doesn't really work all that well:

```
map.namespace :account do |account|
..
end
```

The previous code will load the files from the locations I want, however it does add the namespace to the url and the generated paths so I'll have methods such as `account_account_posts_url` and similar paths.

Another alternative is to use something like:

```
account.resource :profile, :controller => 'account/profile'
```

I really don't like this as it involves both code duplication and forces me to remove some of the rails magic helpers.

Any thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: See my update for something that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my `routes.rb` and running `rake routes` I came up with the following:

```
map.resources :accounts do |accounts|
  accounts.namespace :account do |account|
    account.resource :profile, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

This gets you what you want. The correct url and pointing to `account/...` controller.

See [Rails Routing](http://guides.rails.info/routing.html) for more detailed info and options on what can be done with Rails Routes.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't know who modded you down, but you definitely get a +1 from me.

Comment: No worries. Glad you got the route definitions you needed. The down mark was more than likely due to the `I haven't tried this so have no idea if it will work` statement.

Answer (score 0):

So what's specifically wrong with namespacing? I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
map.namespace :account do |account|
  account.resource :profile
end
```

This will try to load the controller at *app/controllers/account/profiles_controller.rb* and will generate routes such as `account_profile_path`.

**Updated based on comment**:

```
map.resources :accounts do |account| 
 account.resource :profile
end
```

Will give you */accounts/22/profile*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for not being to clear, but what I'm after is a route that looks like this:
/accounts/22/profile
The above code would generate account/profile.